# 2D tile game map storage

Tags: android

I'm new to game programming, and am trying to write the Map storage portion of my 2D tile based game on android. At first, my plan was to store the maps in XML. I found a tool (http://www.mapeditor.org/) that stores the created maps in a format close to what I was thinking. However, it seems like Android is very limited when it comes to XML. I'm used to working with XML Beans which doesn't work on Android, though I admit XML Beans would probably be too resource heavy for mobile devices anyways. However, after searching around for XML parser options, it seems like even basic XML validation isn't even included by default with the Android SDK. It's starting to look like XML might not be the best answer.

Does anyone know of a good standard way to store map configuration besides XML? Or some strong XML tools available in Android that handle validation (against a defined schema), and preferably simple parsing? I would really like to avoid defining my own flat file text format for maps...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/). If I remember correctly AndEngine already has the classes needed to load a map from an XML file for rendering.

As far as a standard way to store map configurations, I would say XML is the way to go. I mean you could create your own format, but why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't heard of AndEngine. Looks like it's open source so I can see how he handles reading in the XML files. Thanks, this should be really useful.

Comment: Taking a look at the code, all he's doing is manually defining what elements/attributes to parse for. No validation that I could find. Doesn't even have a copy of the defined Tiled schema (map.xsd). Basically, if that schema ever changed, AndEngine would fail without a real indicator of why. I was hoping to discover a mature XML tool to use with Android. Ohh well. His code base will still be useful as a reference when I'm designing my own framework. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I parse XML in Android with javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory and various other XML parts. It hasn't failed me yet!

For example see: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Kind of looks similar to XMLPull, which I used on another Android project. The limitation I had there was that it became a complete nightmare to work with for anything but extremely simple Schemas. Fortunately, what I currently have planned for maps isn't very complicated. But I imagine that's going to change as I get further =P. Are you able to validate against a schema, or are you basically just hard coding element/attribute names in the code and hoping you don't run into a typo in the xml?